# What is the correct PayPal API workflow for PayOut feedback?

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I cannot seem to find the documentation for this workflow in the [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/).

We are making PayOuts to individuals via PayPal using the [C# .Net PayPal SDK](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK/).

We want to get the Transaction ID for the payout to store back against our payment records.

Currently I creating the PayOut (via `Payout.Create`) and that this point the batch status is `PENDING` and there is no Transaction Id

I then repeatedly Get the PayOut (via `Payout.Get`) with a exponentially-backed-off delay interval until the batch status changes (`SUCCESS`,`UNCLAIMED`,`DENIED` etc.), and/or there is a batch error reported, or we have tried too many times.

Is this the correct approach? Should I be using another technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PayPal-NET-SDK is deprecated and should not be used. Most PayPal REST API operations should be done with direct HTTPS call integrations in JSON format (no SDK)

In the [REST Application](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications) you are processing payouts with, you can register a webhook event listener URL. There are [various events](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#batch-payouts) for payouts, including `PAYMENT.PAYOUTS-ITEM.SUCCEEDED`

Comment: Correct, but amazing so little is done to stop people using this given that it's now deprecated 3 years ago. Also they do say in the docs that it's ok to use it, and in fact it's still easier to use it and poll for transaction status than set up webhooks and ngrok locally.